# Writing an OkHttp Interceptor that compresses request body

Tags: java, retrofit, java-io, okhttp, gzipoutputstream

I'm trying to write an interceptor that compresses a request body using Gzip.

My server does not support compressed requests, so I'll be using an `application/octet-stream` **instead of** `Content-Type: gzip` and compress the request body manually, it will be decompressed manually at backend.

```
public class GzipRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    final String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/octet-stream";

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        if (originalRequest.body() == null || CONTENT_TYPE.equals(originalRequest.header("Content-Type"))) {
            return chain.proceed(originalRequest);
        }

        Request compressedRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Content-Type", CONTENT_TYPE)
                .method(originalRequest.method(), gzip(originalRequest.body()))
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(compressedRequest);
    }

    private RequestBody gzip(final RequestBody body) throws IOException {

        final Buffer inputBuffer = new Buffer();
        body.writeTo(inputBuffer);

        final Buffer outputBuffer = new Buffer();
        GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(outputBuffer.outputStream());

        gos.write(inputBuffer.readByteArray());

        inputBuffer.close();
        gos.close();

        return new RequestBody() {
            @Override
            public MediaType contentType() {
                return body.contentType();
            }

            @Override
            public long contentLength() {
                return outputBuffer.size();
            }

            @Override
            public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                ByteString snapshot = outputBuffer.snapshot();
                sink.write(snapshot);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

It doesn't work - 30 seconds after request is fired, a `500 Server Error` is received. On the server there's a timeout exception.

My guess is that I've done wrong with input/output on the gzip method... any ideas?

**Update** if I stop the app, the request goes through successfully, does this indicate that the app is still waiting for data from outputBuffer?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for [Interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors), check the Rewriting Requests -chapter.

Comment: Basically the code above is based on that example, only I read the whole thing to have the content size.